# Can I use a picture on my computer as my website's background?

Tags: html, background-image

I have a problem with setting up a background image. My html below works perfectly when I use a url to a picture online, however I can't use a picture from my computer. Can I use a picture on my computer as my website's background?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <style>
       body {
         background-image: url("Downloads/jpic.jpg");
         background-color: #cccccc;
       }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <p>first paragraph</p>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to server it from a web server.

Comment: Try `url("file:///C:\Path\Downloads\jpic.jpg")`.

Comment: You can do this but no one else will see the picture if they visit your page.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your path you need to specify the path like this if your image is not in the same directory as your project :

'C:\Users\user1\Downloads\jpic.jpg'

try it this way it will work

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may use background-image from your computer. Just put the image(which you want to use) in the same folder in which your coding file is located.
After pasting your image file to the same folder, just use the code below:

```
    background-image: url("jpic.jpg");
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful ? @Nazanin

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path (without C:\, Documents or whatever) just where the image is from all the other files included in the project. For example if its in the same path it would be:

```
body {
  background-image: url("jpic.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

And in the images path:

```
body {
  background-image: url("images/jpic.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

And please avoid inline CSS, import external *.css file